# window.location.replace is not working in my sharepoint site

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using JavaScript on my sharepoint search box. but `window.location.replace` function is not working? Here is my code:

```
$('.SearchBtnGo').click(function(){
    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
    var value=$('#ctl00_ctl55_csr_sbox').val(); //Taking value from search box 
    var SearchUrl = url+"/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?k=";
    var NewUrl=SearchUrl+value;
    alert(NewUrl); // i am getting expected URL in alert.
    window.location.replace(NewUrl);
});
```

I am getting expected URL in alert box. But it is not redirecting to the new URL. I even used just `window.location` But I am getting the same result. Can someone help me out?

Comment: @Satpal I tried, but getting the same result.

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: @Script47 I am not getting any error in console. only the page gets refreshed. Neither it redirects to new page...not the URL gets changed.

Comment: e.preventDefault();  worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the default action of the button so the form doesn't submit, otherwise it will go to the url of the form rather than the url of the `window.location.replace`

```js
$('.SearchBtnGo').click(function(e){ // add an e to this function argument
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent the default action of the button

    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
    var value=$('#ctl00_ctl55_csr_sbox').val(); //Taking value from search box 
    var SearchUrl = url+"/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?k=";
    var NewUrl=SearchUrl+value;
    alert(NewUrl); // i am getting expected URL in alert.
    window.location.replace(NewUrl);
});
```

Comment: I tried  but i am getting error in console stating "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined".

Comment: did you put the `e` in the function too @DilipKumarYadav (see first 2 lines of the above code)

Comment: Yuppp @pete.I had forgot that. but now it worked. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, i solved this by using window.open, then assigning the second parameter according to what i wanted the click of the button to do.

```
window.open(NewUrl, '_self');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: Yup it workes. But opens it in new window. so i used e.preventDefault() , and it worked as desired.

Comment: Like i said, if you used the link above, you can get the result you desire by merely changing the second parameter.

Comment: Glad i could help :) I had an issue where the link would simply get added to the end of the current URL i had.